# Neural network keeps misclassifying input image despite performing well on the original data set

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

[Link to the dataset in question](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sachinpatel21/az-handwritten-alphabets-in-csv-format)

Before I begin, few things that might be relevant:

- The input file format is JPEG. I convert them to `numpy` arrays using `matplotlib`'s `imread`
- The RGB images are then reshaped and converted to grayscale images using `tensorflow`'s `image.resize` method and `image.rgb_to_grayscale` method respectively.

This is my model:

```
model = Sequential(
    [
        tf.keras.Input(shape=(784,),),
        Dense(200, activation= "relu"),
        Dense(150, activation= "relu"),
        Dense(100, activation= "relu"),
        Dense(50, activation= "relu"),
        Dense(26, activation= "linear")
    ]
)
```

The neural network scores a 98.9% accuracy on the dataset. However, when I try to use an image of my own, it always classifies the input as 'A'.

I even went to the extent of inverting the colors of the image (black to white and vice versa; the original grayscale image had the alphabet in black and the rest in white).

```
img = plt.imread("20220922_194823.jpg")
img = tf.image.rgb_to_grayscale(img)
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

Which displays [this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICXSj.png)

`img.shape` returns `TensorShape([675, 637, 1])`

```
img = 1 - img
img = tf.image.resize(img, [28,28]).numpy()
plt.imshow(img, cmap="gray")
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xddtz.png) is the result of `img = 1-img`

I suspect that the neural network keeps classifying the input image as 'A' because of some pixels that aren't completely black/white.

But why does it do that? How do I avoid this problem in the future?

[Here's the notebook.](https://www.kaggle.com/code/rahulsundarram/handwrittencharrecognition)

Comment: And yes, I do subject the linear activations to the softmax function to obtain the probabilities.

Comment: Can you update your question with any preprocessing methods used on the training data and prediction image?

Comment: Do you use a validation set during training? What is the accuracy there?

Comment: @AndrzejO, yes I do use a dev/cross-validation set and a test set. The model achieves a 99.5% accuracy rate on the test set.

Comment: @Djinn sorry, I am quite new to neural networks/machine learning in general. I did look up on image pre-processing after you had mentioned it and as far as I can tell, I haven't applied any pre-processing techniques on the image.

Comment: Can you show the code on how you load the train images and test image? And how you applied softmax. And also how you pass the data to the model. The model definition itself is only a small amount of information.

Comment: There is usually code attached or linked (to the datasets on Kaggle) that can show a quick preview of test images that are input into the neural network and the classification of the neural network annotated. At that point, you could use the same plotting code to preview your image, in order to do some basic sanity checking, to see if it looks anything like the training images. The issue is likely with how you read your image that keeps getting misclassified. That, or it simply doesn't look close enough to what the NN has been trained on.

Comment: @Djinn [Here's the link to the notebook](https://www.kaggle.com/code/rahulsundarram/handwrittencharrecognition)

Comment: Also, I suspect that there might be some other bug in your code if it keeps ending up in "A", the very first category. If you feed it several input images, maybe hand-drawn ones, of different letters, then one would probably expect them to be all over the categories. So, also try to output the raw values you get from the neural network, from the last layer, before you output your probabilities with softmax. You should still be able to see how the activations on the final layer look, even if they are not normalized via softmax. If that looks okay but not the softmax, that might be your issue.

Comment: @alt_zancudo I see the accuracy is being calculated using the argmax of the outputs (code block 11). But you also said something about using softmax. Try just looking at the activations of the last layer after feeding in your image, in order to minimize the code and narrow down the problem. I also don't see any code to read in custom images (the ones misclassified), just the data set you trained on. As I had suspected above, there is pyplot code to preview the images that work. For the ones misclassified, try to preview them in the same way and use the same codepaths as much as possible.

Comment: I have just downloaded the neural network and ran it on my machine. It's working fine and I think I know what's wrong. I will explain it in an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have downloaded and tested your model. The accuracy was as stated by you, when run against the Kaggle dataset. You were also on the right track with inverting the values of the input for your own image, the one that wasn't working. But you should have taken a look at the training inputs: the values are in the range of 0-255, while you're inverting the values with 1-x, assuming floating points from 0-1. I have drawn a simple "X" and "P" in Paint, saved it as a PNG (should work the same way with JPEG), and the neural network identifies them just fine. For that, I rescale it with OpenCV, grayscale it, then invert it (the white pixels had values of 255, while the training inputs use 0 for the blank pixels).

Here is a rough code of what I have done:

```
import numpy as np
import keras
import cv2

def load_image(path):
    image = cv2.imread(path)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    image = 255 - cv2.resize(image, (28,28))
    image = image.reshape((1,784))
    return image

def load_dataset(path):
    dataset = np.loadtxt(path, delimiter=',')
    X = dataset[:,0:784]
    Y = dataset[:,0]
    return X, Y

def benchmark(model, X, Y):
    test_count = 100
    tests = np.random.randint(0, X.shape[0], test_count)
    correct = 0
    p = model.predict(X[tests])
    for i, ti in enumerate(tests):
        if Y[ti] == np.argmax(p[i]):
            correct += 1
    print(f'Accuracy: {correct / test_count * 100}')

def recognize(model, image):
    alph = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    p = model.predict(image)[0]
    letter = alph[np.argmax(p)]
    print(f'Image prediction: {letter}')

    top3 = dict(sorted(
        zip(alph, 100 * np.exp(p) / sum(np.exp(p))), 
        key=lambda x: x[1],
        reverse=True)[:3])
    print(f'Top 3: {top3}')

img_x = load_image('x.png')
img_p = load_image('p.png')
X, Y = load_dataset('chardata.csv')
model = keras.models.load_model('CharRecognition.h5')
benchmark(model, X, Y)
recognize(model, img_x)
recognize(model, img_p)
```

The predictions are "x" and "p", respectively. I haven't tried other letters, yet, but the issues identified above seem to be part of the problem with high certainty.

Here are the images I have used (as I said, both are hand-drawn, nothing generated):

[image: Sample input for neural network X]
[image: Sample input for neural network P]

I have also run it with the image as a JPEG. All you need to do is change the file path for `imread`. OpenCV detects the format. If you don't want to or can't use OpenCV and still have trouble, I can expand on the answer. It might go beyond the scope of your actual question, though. Relevant documentation: [OpenCV Documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html).  Pillow and scikit-image would work very similarly.

I noticed that the outputs produce values with high variation - many values are being printed with long scientific notation. It makes it hard to assess the output of the neural network. Therefor, when you're not using a softmax layer, you can also calculate the probabilities separately, as I did in `recognize` (see [Wikipedia: Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) for the formula and more explanation). I'm mentioning it here because it can be a help troubleshooting such issues in the future and make it easier on other people trying to help you out.

For the images above, it produces something like this, which shows that there is a high certainty about the category:

```
Image prediction: x
Top 3: {'x': 100.0, 'a': 0.0, 'b': 0.0}
Image prediction: p
Top 3: {'p': 100.0, 'd': 2.6237523e-09, 'q': 7.537843e-12}
```

Why was the prediction always "a" in your case? Assuming you didn't do any other mistakes, I'd have to guess, but I think it's probably because the letter occupies a large amount of the area in the image, so an inverted image that had most areas filled in would resemble it most closely. Or, the inverted image of an "a" looked to the neural network most closely to the images of "a" it saw during training. It's a guess. But if you give a neural network something it never really saw during training, I think the best anyone can do is guess at the outcome. I would have expected it to be more randomly spread among the categories, probably, so there might be some other issue in your code, possibly with evaluating the prediction.

Just out of curiosity, I have used two more images, which don't look like letters at all:

[image: Nonsense]
[image]

The first image the neural network insists is an "e":

```
Top 3: {'e': 99.99985, 's': 0.00014580016, 'c': 1.3610912e-06}
```

The second image it believes to be, with high certainty, an "a":

```
Top 3: {'a': 100.0, 'h': 1.28807605e-08, 'r': 1.0681121e-10}
```

It might be that random images of that sort simply "look like an a" to your neural network. Also, it has been known that neural networks can, at times, be easily fooled and hone in on features that seem very counterintuitive: [Jiawei Su, Danilo Vasconcellos Vargas, and Sakurai Kouichi, “One Pixel Attack for Fooling Deep Neural Networks,” IEEE Transactions on Evolutionary Computation 23, no. 5 (October 2019): 828–41, https://doi.org/10.1109/TEVC.2019.2890858](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.08864).

I think there is also a lesson to be learned about training neural networks in general: I had the expectation that, in a case of a classification problem as you are solving, which seems to have become almost like a canonical introductory problem in many machine learning courses, an input that does not clearly belong to any of the trained classes, even in a well-trained network, would manifest itself as predictions that are spread out over several classes, signifying the ambiguity of the input. But, as we can see here, an "unknown" input does not need to produce such results at all, apparently. Even such a case can produce results that seem to show a high certainty that the input belong in a certain class, such as the apparent degree of "certainty" the neural network suggests to have that the nonsensical scribble be an "e".

Therefor, another conclusion can perhaps be drawn: if one wants to appropriately deal with inputs that do not belong to any of the trained categories, one must train the neural network for that purpose *explicitly*. By that I mean that one must add an additional class of *non-alphabetic* images and train it with images that are non-sensical, miscellaneous images (such as the flower above), or probably even classes very close to letters, such as numbers and non-latin writing symbols. It might be precisely the closeness of that "miscellaneous category" that could help the neural network get a clearer idea of what constitutes a letter. However, as we can see here, it seems insufficient to train a neural network on a set of target classes and then to simply expect it to also be able to give a useful prediction in the case of inputs outside of those classes. Some people might feel that I am way overthinking and complicating the topic at this point, but I think it's important enough of an observation about neural networks that, at least for myself, it is well worth keeping in mind.

## Preprocessing Images

From the exchange in the comments, it turns out that there is another aspect to this problem. The images I had drawn happened to work very well. However, when I increase the contrast, they are no longer being recognized. I will first go into how I have done so. Since it is a common function in machine learning, I had the somewhat unconventional idea to apply a scaled sigmoid function, so as to keep the values in the range of 0-255, retain some of the relative shades, but turn up the contrast. More on that here: [Wikipedia: Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function). I'm saying "unconventional" because I don't think it's something you usually use for images, but since this function is so ubiquitous in machine learning, specifically the activation functions, I thought it might be fun to repurpose it, even though the performance is probably terrible compared to algorithms that are more common for image processing.

*(Aside: I had done almost the exact same for audio processing once, which ended up, when applied to the volume, to function like a compressor. And that's sort of what we're doing: we're "compressing" the grayscale ranges here, without completely eliminating the transitions. This, I believe, ended up really pinpointing the issue with this neural network, because it's a modification that seems more specific, but proceeds to throw off the neural network almost right away. Adjust the parameters in this "generalized sigmoid" function a bit, if you like, to make it smoother (That means: less steep, to retain more of the transitions. Play around with the Desmos graph and look at the PyPlot previews, too.) and get a better feel for at what point precisely the neural network sort of gives up and says "I don't recognize this anymore." People more graphically inclined might also be reminded of the `smoothstep` function often used to adjust harshness of edges in shaders [GLSL: smoothstep](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/smoothstep.xhtml)).*

[image: Desmos Sigmoid]
[Desmos Graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gi9mo87k9a)

Formula (s = 25, b = 50 appear to give good results):

[image: Formula]

Then, I preprocess the images with code like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def preprocess(before):
    s, b = 25, 50
    f = lambda x: np.exp(s*(x/255 - s/b)) / (1 + np.exp(s*(x/255 - s/b)))
    after = f(before)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
    ax[0].imshow(before, cmap='gray')
    ax[1].imshow(after, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()

    return after
```

Call the above in `load_image`, before reshaping it. It will show you the result, side-by-side, before feeding the image to the neural network. In general, not just in machine learning but also statistics, it appears to be good practice to get an idea of the data, to preview and sanity check it, before further working with it. This might have also given you a hint early on about what was wrong with your input images.

Here is an example, using the images from above, of what these look like before and after preprocessing:

[image: High Contrast 1]
[image: High Contrast 2]

Considering it was such an ad-hoc idea and somewhat unconventional, it seems to work quite well. However, here are the new predictions for these images, after processing:

```
Image prediction: l
Top 3: {'l': 11.176592, 'y': 9.341431, 'x': 7.692416}

Image prediction: q
Top 3: {'q': 11.703363, 'p': 9.119178, 'l': 7.6522427}
```

It doesn't recognize those images at all anymore, which confirms some of the issues you might have been having. Your neural network has "learned" the grey, fuzzy transitions around the letters to be part of the features it considers. I had used this site to draw the images: [JSPaint](https://jspaint.app/). Maybe it was, in part, luck or intuition that I used the paintbrush and not the pen tool, as I would have probably encountered the same issues you are having, since it produces no transitions from black to white. That seemed natural to me, because it seemed to best fit the "feel" of your training inputs, even if it seemed like a trivial, negligible detail at first. Luck, experience - I don't know. But what you therefor want to do is use a tool that leaves "fuzzy borders" or write yet another preprocessing step that does the reverse of what I have just demonstrated, in order to show the negative case, and add blur to the borders.

## Data Augmentation

I thought I would have been long since done with this question, but it really goes to show how involved dealing with neural networks can quickly get, it seems. The core of the problem of this question really appears to  end up touching on what seems to be some of the fundamentals of machine learning. I will state plainly what I think this example ended up demonstrating, quite illustratively, maybe more for myself than for most other readers:

> Your neural network only learns what you teach it.

The explanation might be simply, and probably there are important exceptions to his, that you didn't teach your neural network to recognize letters with sharp borders, so it didn't learn how to recognize them. I'm not a great machine learning expert, so probably none of this is news to anyone more experienced. But this reminded me of a technique in machine learning that I think could be applied in this scenario quite well, which is "data augmentation":

> Data augmentation in data analysis are techniques used to increase the amount of data by adding slightly modified copies of already existing data or newly created synthetic data from existing data. It acts as a regularizer and helps reduce overfitting when training a machine learning model.

[Wikipedia: Data Augmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_augmentation)

[Perez, Luis, and Jason Wang. “The Effectiveness of Data Augmentation in Image Classification Using Deep Learning.” arXiv, December 13, 2017. https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.1712.04621.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.04621)

The good news might be that I have given you everything you need to train your neural network further, without needing any additional data on top of the hundreds of megabytes of training data you are already loading from that CSV file. Use the contrast-enhancing preprocessing function above to create a variation of each of the training images, during learning, so that it learns to also handle such variations.

- Would another model architecture end up being less picky about such details?
- Would different activation functions have handled these cases more flexibly, perhaps?

I don't know, but those seem like very interesting questions for machine learning in general.

## Debugging Neural Networks

This answer has taken on dimensions I really did not intend, so I'm starting to feel the urge to apologize for adding on to it yet again, but this immediately leads one to wonder about a broader issue, one which has probably plagued the machine learning community (or at least someone with as humble experience in it as myself):

How do you debug a neural network?

So far, this was a bunch of trial and error, some luck, a little bit of intuition, but it feels like shooting in the dark sometimes when a neural network is not working. This might be far from perfect, but one approach that seems have been spreading online is to visualize which neurons activate for a given input, in order to get an idea of what areas in an image, or input more generally, influence the final prediction of a neural network most.

For that, Keras already provides some functionality, by giving you access to the outputs of each model layer. As a reminder, the architecture of the model in question looks like this:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 dense (Dense)               (None, 200)               157000                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 150)               30150                                                                  
 dense_2 (Dense)             (None, 100)               15100                                                                  
 dense_3 (Dense)             (None, 50)                5050                                                                  
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 26)                1326      
                                                             
=================================================================
Total params: 208,626
Trainable params: 208,626
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

You can get access to the activations of each layer by creating a new model and combine the outputs of each layer. That we can plot. Now, it would be a lot easier of those were CNN's, and those might be more appropriate for an image, but that's fine. The author of the question wasn't comfortable with those, yet, so let's go with what we have. With CNN layers we would naturally have a 2-dimensional shape to plot, but a dense layer of neurons is one dimensional. What I like to do in scenarios like that, even though it's less than perfect, is to pad them up to the next larger square.

```
def trace(model, image):
    outputs = [layer.output for layer in model.layers] 
    trace_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=outputs)
    p = trace_model.predict(image) 

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, len(p))
    for i, layer in enumerate(p):
        neurons = layer[0].shape[0]
        square = int(np.ceil(np.sqrt(neurons)))
        padding = square**2 - neurons
        activations = np.append(layer[0], [np.min(layer[0])]*padding).reshape((square,square))
        ax[i].imshow(activations)

    plt.show()
```

As I said, this would be nicer with CNN layers, which is why most sources on the Internet related to this topic will use those, so I thought suggesting something for dense layers might be useful.

Here are the results, for the same images of the letter "x" and "p" from above:

[image: Activations for x]
[image: Activations for p]

We can see an image being plotted, per figure, one for each layer of the neural network. This colormap is "viridis", as far as I know, the current default colormap for pyplot, where blue are the lowest values and yellow the highest. You can see the padding at the end of the image for each layer, except where it happens to be a perfect square already (such in the case of 100). There might be a better way to clearly delineate those. In the case of "p", the second image, one can make out the final classification, from the output of the final layer, as the brightest, most yellow dot is on the third line, fourth column ("p" is the 16th letter of the alphabet, 16 = 2x6+4, as the next higher square for 26 letters was 36, so it ends up in a 6x6 square).

It's still somewhat difficult to get a clear answer for what's wrong or what's going on here, but it might be a useful start. Other instances, using CNN's, show a lot more clearly what kind of shapes trigger the neural network, but a variation of this technique could perhaps be adopted to dense layers as well. To make a careful attempt at interpreting these images, it does seem to possibly confirm that the neural network is very specific about the feature it learns about an image, as the singular bright, yellow spot in the first layer of both of these images might suggest. What one would more likely expect, ideally, is probably that the neural network considers more features, with similar weights, across the image, thus paying more attention to the overall shape of the letter. However, I am less sure about this and it's probably non-trivial to properly interpret these "activation plots".

Comment: I think one-hot encoding labels is supposed to help mitigate models defaulting to certain classes based on class value alone. For example, if cat and dog are represented as 0 and 1, the model may default to 1. But it's not as easy to default to [1, 0] over [0, 1]. Also just guessing as a potential problem source :)

Comment: @Djinn I'm not sure neural networks generally have such defaults, but maybe I misunderstand. I think there are techniques in machine learning that employ certain strategies for that, such as "Xavier" or "He" (https://keras.io/api/layers/initializers/). I'm not sure right now if one-hot encodings should have an impact on such a scenario, where the issue appears to be inputs it's not been trained on.

Comment: Not a default as in "if it fails, pick this" but the statistic nature of integer values in comparisons. Without encoded labels, each class has a comparable value, which can affect classification. If a model seems to be biased towards a class when the train data is fairly balanced, encoded labels could help. That didn't seem to be the problem here though, just saying information about classification bias.

Comment: Defaulting wasn't the right word, should've been "being biased towards"

Comment: Oh, I see. You might be right on that. I'm probably only going to make things worse and more confusing at this point. I'm cleaning up the answer before ending my day, but I will read your input in more detail soon when I'm rested. I'm probably not doing it justice right now.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the issue still persists. It seems like the neighboring pixels containing even the slightest shade of gray affects the neural network big time. I converted the original handwritten image to a 28x28, but this time, I painted the pixels that weren't white with black using paint. And it kinda worked? I still need to test it out with other handwritten alphabets though.

Comment: I have also found another work around I think? I padded the image with a black border of 10px width and resized it to a 28x28 image. The network is able to classify it correctly this time. Again, I have to test this with other examples as well. So as far as I know (also by reading your answer :D), the issue might be that the neighboring pixels are "noisy" and throwing off the network or that the alphabet occupies a considerable portion of the image.

Comment: @alt_zancudo Those are some very interesting observations you are raising there, I think. I did think about this problem a little more last night and I think it is related precisely to the two extra paragraphs I have written just now. If you want your neural network to deal with shades of grey, you must also train it with such inputs. It might sound obvious and dismissive, but I think it's precisely those sort of assumptions that result in surprises like these. The surprises about neural networks, I think, have been part of the most interesting aspects of the field.

Comment: @alt_zancudo If you do not want to go that route, the simplest way to address this issue might be to just increase the contrast and reduce the range of gray tones. The math to do so should be simple. It should be possible to add a few more lines to the image loading code to do this sort of preprocessing. I wonder if a sigmoid function might be an interesting way to turn the lightest pixels white and the darkest black. But that's probably a bit unusual. It would be helpful if you could post your input images you're having trouble with in your question. I am still a little unclear what you use.

Comment: What I said in my last comment was the reverse of what the issue is: the sharp borders *without* transitions appear to cause issues. It is the soft, fuzzy-bordered versions the neural network works with well. If you want the neural network to learn this, you must teach it, it seems. Include sharp-bordered images. But you can generate those on-the-fly, with the code I showed.

It goes to show how fragile and surprising the machine learning process can be. Really gives you an appreciation for how careful one probably needs to be in more serious scenarios, such as self-driving cars.

Comment: @BananaMango Just read through your entire answer. Just wow! Explained in really simple terms and yet, it makes so much sense and goes into so much detail. Thanks a lot again and stay safe :D

Comment: Thank you. You're welcome! I was concerned I might have overshot the target. I'm afraid to say that I would like to add yet another point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248306/discussion-between-bananamango-and-alt-zancudo).